# Format a pandas dataframe with floats and leading zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I need to display (not modify) the float values in a very particular way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1000.5, 100000.78, -90000, -900.4],
                  index=['row1','row2','row3','row4'],
                  columns=['amount'])
print(df)

        amount
row1    1000.50
row2  100000.78
row3  -90000.00
row4    -900.40
```

the whole string should be 9 characters long (including minus sign and decimal separator)
,
the int part should have leading zeros,

the decimal part should also have filling zeros and be limited to 2 decimals

I would like to coerce this into printing (without modifying original values):

```
            amount
row1    001000.50
row2    100000.78
row3    -90000.00
row4    -00900.40
```

this is what  I tried without much luck:

```
df['amount'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:.2f}')
df['newamount'] = df['amount'].astype(str)
width = 9
df['newamount']= df['newamount'].str.zfill(width)
print(df)

       amount   newamount
row1    1000.50     0001000.5
row2  100000.78     100000.78
row3  -90000.00     0-90000.0
row4    -900.40     000-900.4
```

keep in mind there are other float columns in the dataframe that should not be displayed this way

Comment: Change your format string to be `{x:09.2f}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the display `float_format` option as `'{:09.2f}'.format`:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:09.2f}'.format
df    
        amount
row1 001000.50
row2 100000.78
row3 -90000.00
row4 -00900.40
```

But this will only change the current display. If you need to create a new column, you can use an `f` string:

```
df['newamount'] = df.amount.apply(lambda x: f'{x:09.2f}')
df    
         amount  newamount
row1    1000.50  001000.50
row2  100000.78  100000.78
row3  -90000.00  -90000.00
row4    -900.40  -00900.40
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple !!. Thanks for the answer. The second example was what I needed.

Comment: @Christian1971 note that `lambda` isn't really required here... you can use `df.amount.apply('{:09.2f}'.format)`...

Comment: @Jon Clements. Thanks for your answer, that works too.

Comment: @Christian1971 and depending on what you're doing with the results, you may want to check out styling, eg: `df.style.format('{:09.2f}', subset=['amount'])`

Comment: @Jon Clements. Thanks for your time.